# Optimizing degrees of freedom in spline regression

Tags: r, regression, spline, gam, mgcv

I have two gene-expression time-course data sets:

First, gene expression was measured over 14 time points from 4 groups:

```
df1 <- structure(list(val = c(-0.1, -0.13, -0.4, -0.3, -0.3, -0.2, -0.24, 
                            0.1, 0.2, 0.13, 0, 0.63, 0.83, 0.85, -0.07, -0.07, -0.27, -0.2, 
                            -0.2, -0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.07, 0.17, 0.6, 0.75, 1.1, 1.1, -0.13, 
                            -0.15, -0.26, -0.25, -0.14, 0.04, 0.2, 0.24, 0.23, 0.2, 0.1, 
                            0.73, 1, 1.3, 0, 0.06, -0.24, -0.17, -0.17, -0.04, 0.16, 0.1, 
                            0.14, 0.27, 0.34, 0.9, 0.97, 1.04), 
                    time = c(-1, 0, 1, 1.58,2, 2.58, 3, 3.32, 3.58, 4.17, 4.58, 5.58, 6.17, 7.39, 
                             -1, 0, 1, 1.58, 2, 2.58, 3, 3.32, 3.58, 4.17, 4.58, 5.58, 6.17, 7.39, 
                             -1, 0, 1, 1.58, 2, 2.58, 3, 3.32, 3.58, 4.17, 4.58, 5.58, 6.17,7.39, 
                             -1, 0, 1, 1.58, 2, 2.58, 3, 3.32, 3.58, 4.17, 4.58, 5.58,6.17, 7.39), 
                    group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                        2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                        3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L,3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                        4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L,4L), 
                                      .Label = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("val","time", "group"), 
               row.names = c(NA, -56L), class = "data.frame")


df1$group <- factor(df1$group,levels=c("a","b","c","d"))
```

which looks like this (adding a `loess` smoothed trend line):

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df1,aes(x=time,y=val,color=group))+geom_point()+theme_minimal()+geom_smooth(se=F)+theme(legend.position="top",legend.title=element_blank())
```

[image]

Second, gene expression was measured over similar 14 time points but now from 2 different groups, each represented by the two sexes:

```
df2 <- structure(list(val = c(-0.23, -0.01, -0.14, -0.01, -0.21, -0.16, 
                       -0.24, -0.11, 0.02, -0.11, -0.01, -0.25, -0.47, -1.25, 0.02, 
                       -0.3, -0.02, 0.14, 0.25, -0.05, 0.15, 0.11, -0.24, -0.18, -0.39, 
                       -0.49, -0.5, -0.65, -0.06, 0.09, 0.1, 0.15, 0.08, 0.15, 0.4, 
                       0.24, 0.07, 0.08, -0.18, -0.35, -0.19, -0.81, -0.16, 0.29, -0.05, 
                       0.14, 0.14, 0.48, 0.34, 0.11, -0.07, -0.13, -0.41, -0.22, -0.54, 
                       -0.76, 0.35, 0.34, -0.06, 0.21, 0.14, 0.14, 0.25, 0.22, 0.25, 
                       0.16, 0.3, 0.44, 0.08, 0.48, 0.1, 0.16, -0.03, -0.22, 0.2, 0.01, 
                       -0.09, -0.02, -0.01, 0.06, -0.13, 0.19, 0.11, -0.04, -0.39, 0.03, 
                       -0.01, 0.09, 0.1, -0.14, -0.12, -0.1, 0.36, 0.08, 0.09, 0.09, 
                       0.42, 0.37, -0.14, 0.12, 0.09, 0.03, 0.06, -0.25, 0.2, -0.06, 
                       -0.44, 0.23, 0.03, 0.16, 0.81, 0.83),
               time = c(-1, 0, 1, 1.58,2, 2.58, 3, 3.32, 3.58, 4.17, 4.58, 5.58, 6.17, 7.39, 
                        -1, 0,1, 1.58, 2, 2.58, 3, 3.32, 3.58, 4.17, 4.58, 5.58, 6.17, 7.39, 
                        -1, 0, 1, 1.58, 2, 2.58, 3, 3.32, 3.58, 4.17, 4.58, 5.58, 6.17,7.39, 
                        -1, 0, 1, 1.58, 2, 2.58, 3, 3.32, 3.58, 4.17, 4.58, 5.58,6.17, 7.39, 
                        -1, 0, 1, 1.58, 2, 2.58, 3, 3.32, 3.58, 4.17, 4.58,5.58, 6.17, 7.39, 
                        -1, 0, 1, 1.58, 2, 2.58, 3, 3.32, 3.58, 4.17,4.58, 5.58, 6.17, 7.39, 
                        -1, 0, 1, 1.58, 2, 2.58, 3, 3.32, 3.58, 4.17, 4.58, 5.58, 6.17, 7.39, 
                        -1, 0, 1, 1.58, 2, 2.58, 3, 3.32, 3.58, 4.17, 4.58, 5.58, 6.17, 7.39), 
               sex = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
                               .Label = c("F", "M"), class = "factor"), group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                            2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
                                                                                          .Label = c("a", "b"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("val", "time", "sex", "group"), row.names = c(NA, -112L), class = "data.frame")
df2$sex <- ordered(df2$sex,levels=c("M","F"))

df2$group <- ordered(df2$group,levels=c("a","b"))

df2$col <- factor(paste0(df2$group,":",df2$sex))
```

which looks like this (adding a loess smoothed trend line):

```
ggplot(df2,aes(x=time,y=val,color=col))+geom_point()+theme_minimal()+geom_smooth(se=F)+theme(legend.position="top",legend.title=element_blank())
```

[image]

For `df1`, I would like to estimate the effect of `time` on `val`, adjusting for `group`.

For `df2`, I would like to estimate the effect of `time:group` on `val`, adjusting for `sex`.

Looking at the data I thought using `spline` `regression`s would be appropriate so I used the `gam` function from the `mgcv` package, which as far as I understand optimizes the degrees of freedom of the `spline`s fitted to the data.

This is what I fitted for `df1`:

```
mgcv1.fit <- mgcv::gam(val ~ group+s(time),data=df1)
```

Which gives:

```
Family: gaussian 
Link function: identity 

Formula:
val ~ group + s(time)

Estimated degrees of freedom:
7.18  total = 11.18 

GCV score: 0.01258176
```

But 7.18 degrees of freedom seems too much for these data.

For `df2`:

```
mgcv2.fit <- mgcv::gam(val ~ sex+s(time,by=group),data=df2)
```

which gives:

```
Family: gaussian 
Link function: identity 

Formula:
val ~ sex + s(time, by = group)

Estimated degrees of freedom:
1.72  total = 3.72 

GCV score: 0.08522094
```

I guess that in this case I'd imagine the degrees of freedom to be slightly higher.

One more point. Plotting the fitted values for these two data sets:

```
df1$mgcv <- mgcv1.fit$fitted.values
ggplot(df1,aes(x=time,y=mgcv,color=group))+geom_point()+theme_minimal()+geom_smooth(se=F)+theme(legend.position="top",legend.title=element_blank())
```

[image]

which looks fine.

But for `df2`

```
df2$mgcv <- mgcv2.fit$fitted.values
ggplot(df2,aes(x=time,y=mgcv,color=col))+geom_point()+theme_minimal()+geom_smooth(se=F)+theme(legend.position="top",legend.title=element_blank())
```

[image]

Looks like it flipped the group labels.

So my questions are:

1. Am I using `mgcv::gam` correctly for optimizing the spline degrees of freedom for my questions?
2. Does `mgcv` reorders the samples in its `fitted.values`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, `mgcv` does the right thing on the factor levels. If you check `str(df2$sex)`, you will see that "M" (male) is the first level and "F" (female) is the second. But it seems from `str(df2$col)` that "F" is the first, so you get some mislabeling when making plot.

Secondly, your second model has not been specified correctly.

1. The spline `s(time)` is under centering constraint when there is no "by" variable, or the "by" is a factor. So you to provide your "by" variable `group` as a separate term in your model formula to catch its marginal effect;
2. Since the "by" variable `group` is an ordered variable, `mgcv` applies contrasts on it, dropping the first level "a" when constructing the `s(time, by = group)`. So you need to provide a separate `s(time)` as the baseline smooth.

Your current `mgcv2.fit` is a rather poor model (not surprising), giving an explained deviance of 9%. But if you do the following you get 64%.

```
gam(val ~ sex + s(time) + group + s(time, by = group), data = df2, method = "REML")
```

The `ggplot` now looks right (I haven't changed `df2$col` so the coloring is still probably reversed).

[image]

`gam` defaults to use "GCV.Cp" as smoothing parameter selection method. But it is recommended to use "REML" as it is less prone to overfitting.

---

**Remark 1**

If the "by" variable `group` is a (non-ordered) factor, it is not subject to contrasts. So the model formula should be:

```
val ~ sex + group + s(time, by = group)
```

The following is quoted from *'by' variables* section of `?gam.models`:

```
 If a ‘by’ variable is a ‘factor’ then it generates an indicator
 vector for each level of the factor, unless it is an ‘ordered’
 factor. In the non-ordered case, the model matrix for the smooth
 term is then replicated for each factor level, and each copy has
 its rows multiplied by the corresponding rows of its indicator
 variable. The smoothness penalties are also duplicated for each
 factor level.  In short a different smooth is generated for each
 factor level (the ‘id’ argument to ‘s’ and ‘te’ can be used to
 force all such smooths to have the same smoothing parameter).
 ‘ordered’ ‘by’ variables are handled in the same way, except that
 no smooth is generated for the first level of the ordered factor
 (see ‘b3’ example below).  This is useful for setting up
 identifiable models when the same smooth occurs more than once in
 a model, with different factor ‘by’ variables.
```

---

**Remark 2**

I am not to judge your model, but there seems to be a clear within-group difference between "F" and "M". From your data we see that "F" and "M" has a bigger difference in group "b" than in group "a". At the moment the effect of `sex` is identical in both groups, and it is just a vertical shift. You can observe this in the above `ggplot` in this answer. It is up to you to decide the model in the end, but just in case that you want to model this `sex-group` interaction, you can do

```
df2$sex_group <- with(df2, interaction(sex, group))  ## the new variable is unordered
test <- gam(val ~ sex + group + s(time, by = sex_group), data = df2, method = "REML")
```

[image]

Note how I provide two factor variables to `by`. An auxiliary variable `sex_group` is created.

Comment: Thanks @李哲源. I agree with you that this example also has a sex * group interaction effect, and thanks a lot for the model. I originally didn't focus on it since the number of knots that I got from the fit seemed too high. But I guess that this is the result according to how `mgcv` optimizes the degrees of freedom.